# Update query with select subquery runs extremely slow on mysql 5.7 but runs super fast on 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.5

I have a digital ocean test server which has ubuntu 14.04 and mysql version 5.5. On the other hand, my production server is ubuntu 16.04 and mysql version is 5.7. I have this update query

```
UPDATE paid_cricduel.fantasy_teams t 
join (select ft.fantasy_team_id, 
             ft.team_captain_id, 
             sum((case 
               when ft.team_captain_id = ccp.cricket_contest_player_id then 2
               when ft.team_vc_id = ccp.cricket_contest_player_id then 1.5
               else 1
             end) *  ccp.player_points) as temp_total 
from fantasy_teams as ft 
join fantasy_team_players ftp on ft.fantasy_team_id=ftp.fantasy_team_id
join cricket_contest_players as ccp on   ftp.cricket_contest_player_id = ccp.cricket_contest_player_id 
where ft.cricket_contest_id=? 
group by ft.fantasy_team_id) temp 
set total_points = temp.temp_total
where temp.fantasy_team_id = t.fantasy_team_id
```

This query runs in 0.3 seconds in my test server but takes a minimum of 25 seconds in my production. Sometimes even 50+ seconds. I have tried different solutions mentioned on stack overflow but nothing seems to work for me.

What the query does is that it takes player points from another table and then picks your team players from another table. Does a summation of all the points of your players. Also, if the player is your team captain then it multiples that player points by 1.5, if it is a vice-captain then by 1.2 otherwise just adds them as it is.

I have had indexes on total_points column and fantasy_team_id as well but i removed them to see if it would make any impact but it did not.

Any help?

Comment: Please add both execution plans. Without them we don't have anything to compare.

Comment: You should check which take longer time: the update or the subquery ?

Comment: @NoDataFound The select query inside takes 0.2 seconds on test and 0.9 on production. So i guess it is mainly the update query which is taking the time.

Comment: Same indexes, same optimization level, only different is the binary?

Comment: @Nic3500 well yes, i tried different solutions mentioned which, included changing some variables in sql here and there but it did not change anything. Everything is same as far as i know.

Comment: another thing that a lot of people do not take into account is the volume of data.... if your test system has 20 records and your production system has 20000 records then there can be a vast difference in performance and different indexes may work better in one than the other.  I agree with The Impaler above... the execution plans will give contributors something to work with.

Comment: Are the server resource specs identical? If your data set is 4gb and the digital ocean server had 4gb of ram and the production server has 3gb, for example, then that would be the difference. How about the disk storage type? ssd, etc. If this is not the problem then I would compare the execution plans.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson they are the exact same databases.

Comment: @MarCPlusPlus Production server is 4 times more faster than the test version.

Comment: OK then you will need to provide explain plans,  all the rest of the comments are just guesses (including mine) until you produce the explain plans so we have a clue what is being done differently in each system.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson i newly learned about the explain syntax. If i try to put it before this update query. It gives me an error. It works for the select query though.

Comment: explain update does not exist in 5.5. Please give us the explains for the select queries as well as "show create table" output for all relevant tables on both databases. Also, "4 times more faster" is not empirical enough. All facets of the production server need to be greater than or equal to the test server in order to rule this out as a possible bottleneck. What is the buffer pool size on both servers? What is the total size of the database?